# how do I protect my iOS app from being cracked?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia, cracking

I have $0.99 iOS app and I'm afraid someone would like to crack it. How can I protect my app from crackers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's very easy with little class, which I implemented:
https://github.com/itruf/crackify

Just import Crackify.h and check:

```
BOOL cracked = [Crackify isCracked];
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for, thx.

Comment: How comes crackify does not show alert when app is downloaded via TestFlight ?

Comment: You can disable cruckify, if you are making development build

Comment: I mean, why don't BOOL cracked = [Crackify isCracked]; true when app is downloaded via TestFlight? How can i do something see the Crackify work?

Comment: @itruf Crackify doesn't support iOS 8.x do you have any other good solution?

Answer (score 3):

these are some check list to check whether your app is cracked.

1. checking plist size
2. checking signer identity
3. checking if binary is crypted
4. checking modified date of info.plist against modified date of
   package

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the store it likely already has been cracked. I wouldn't waste your time trying to combat pirates, no-one has been able to so far. I suggest instead you focus upon building apps that people are willing to pay for, or free apps that are iAd supported.

Comment: I dont think there is anything wrong with trying

Comment: Look my answer, there are some good ways to check it.

Comment: It's not in store yet, I'll submit it in week or two.

Comment: yep. I've tried them all (afaik). Nothing stops the pirates if they want to crack they will, best you'll do is deter the "not very clever wannabe pirates".