# iOS app protection

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I protect my iOS app from being cracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642153/how-do-i-protect-my-ios-app-from-being-cracked)

I'm trying to make my first app and it should cost about 10$. I'm afraid, that a lot of 'hackers' would crack my app and make it totally free. I found a lot of cracked apps in the web. Have you any ideas, how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Also, this app should be **really cool and awesome** if it costs $10. It's a rather high price for an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should search before asking. I've answered same question already, but I will copy solution here.

Old question: [how do I protect my iOS app from being cracked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642153/how-do-i-protect-my-ios-app-from-being-cracked/13642182#13642182)

**Answer:**

It's very easy with little class, which I implemented:
https://github.com/itruf/crackify

Just import Crackify.h and check:

```
BOOL cracked = [Crackify isCracked];
```

Comment: Great, but guess what: A simple MobileSubstrate add-on will patch your class (As it's really easy to do with objc), and will cause your Class to no longer work. It's a cat and mouse game, and I wouldn't be surprised if that's fixed with the next version of AppLoader & Installous.

Comment: There are three stages of protection from cracking and some of them is 'hidden'. So it will be little more hard :)

Comment: Very cool. But like others have said, your app probably wont be hacked, but better safe than sorry. Plus, the amount of users with jail-broken devices is very low. Untethered breaks for iOS 6 haven't been released yet, if ever. My guess is by iOS 7, jailbreaking will be near-impossible.

Comment: @ИванТруфанов Using the objc runtime, all I'd need to do is a simple `method_setImplementation`, and your class is broken. Consider using a C static inline function, which is much harder to replace via a runtime hack.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII I was going to say that (guess what my next tweak will be...)

Comment: @IvanTrufanov MobileSubstrate doesn't care if the 'protection' is 'hidden' (note the quotes), if one returns `NO` from your percious `isJailbroken` and `isCracked` methods, all your effort will be wasted...

Comment: How comes crackify does not show alert when app is downloaded via TestFlight ?

Comment: Disable crackify for development builds

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should worry about it. If people decide to crack your app it will be because you made it popular and you should already be making money. The majority of people do not have a jailbroken iOS device so they won't be looking for pirated apps anyway.

Comment: Good positive negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

None. Its the cat and mouse of the software world. You have to hope there are enough honest people left. If your app is good enough enough good people will pay.